# Using nested lapply to filter for criteria and create multiple data frames

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, lapply

here's a sample of my data named `shipment`:

```
shipment <- read.table(text = 'Week Org     Forecast       Actual Forecast.over..under Accuracy.. Int.Ext
24    1/22/2018 KNI      $5,095       $7,101              $(2,006)       139%    Int 
366  12/31/2018 DAN  $3,387,247   $1,907,435           $1,479,812         56%    Int ', header = T)
```

I would like to create a list of 15 data frames that are filtered for all the possible combinations in these two vectors for columns `Org` and `Int.Ext`, respectively.

```
int.ext <- c("Int","Ext","Total")
site <- c("BAL", "DAN", "LON", "STL", "WC")
```

When I run the code below, I end up with a list but the only data frames that are listed correctly are ones with `Int.Ext` values of "Total". The data frames supposed to be filtered for "Int" or "Ext" do not contain any rows.

```
frames <- lapply(int.ext, function(i){ 
            lapply(site, function(j){ 
                filter(shipment, Org==j, Int.Ext==i)})
                      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to move out of base R, this might be more concise:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

d <- crossing(Org = site,Int.Ext = int.ext)
semi_join(shipment,d)
```

Or if you really need them split into a list of data frames, maybe

```
d <- crossing(Org = site,Int.Ext = int.ext) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
inner_join(shipment,d) %>% split(x = .,f = .$id)
```